# Fetching Distinct dates from a range of dates using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, biometrics

I have been trying to fetch only a list of distinct dates according to the latest time from the table, where I have repeated dates within a given range. i.e.

Given the range;

```
Start Date: 11/1/2017 12:00:00 AM
End Date: 11/20/2017 12:00:00 AM
```

Using the query;

```
var mod = (from m in lstMachineInfo
             where m.RegisterationId == EnrollNumber 
                && m.Date >= startDate 
                && m.Date <= endDate
             select m).Distinct();
```

What I get is;

```
11/9/2017 8:02:09 AM    
11/9/2017 3:22:51 PM    
11/9/2017 5:09:23 PM    
11/10/2017 11:23:04 AM  
11/10/2017 4:19:57 PM   
11/14/2017 10:11:11 AM  
11/14/2017 6:30:30 PM
```

What I want is;

```
11/9/2017 8:02:09 AM    
11/10/2017 11:23:04 AM  
11/14/2017 10:11:11 AM
```

Comment: Try to select the date property instead of everything inside your LINQ query.

Comment: Try `select m.Date`, but you'll get `11/9/2017 0:00:00`, decide if it will fits your task

Comment: @EvZ I am only selecting the dates and registrationId since I am fetching the dates for a specific id, but the problem is I have multiple entries (timestamps) with the same date so it shows me all the list. where I only want to fetch the earliest DateTime, not all the datetime of a date.

Comment: @ASpirin I tried that, throws me an error instead.

Comment: Let's say the first two records in your sample results where returned in the opposite order (i.e. 3pm **then** 8am). Should 3pm be the value returned (since it was the first row) or 8am (since it was the earliest time)?

Comment: @mjwills earliest one sir, not the later one.

Comment: @Mogambo right,  check mjwills answer that should be the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var earlyMod = mod
    .GroupBy(dt => dt.Value.Date)
    .Select(z => z.OrderBy(y => y.Date).First())
    .ToList();
```

`earlyMod` will return the earliest time for each given date. This will execute outside of the database (which would be fine if the number of different time records in a given day is limited).

If instead you want it to execute **inside** of the database, try:

```
var mod = (from m in lstMachineInfo
             where m.RegisterationId == EnrollNumber 
                && m.Date >= startDate 
                && m.Date <= endDate
             select m)
           .GroupBy(a => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(a.Value.Date))
           .Select(z => z.OrderBy(y => y.Date).First()).ToList();
```

Comment: My apologies, it is nullable but the error is still there.

Comment: `var mod = (from m in lstMachineInfo
                              where m.RegisterationId == EnrollNumber &&  m.Date >= startDate && m.Date <= endDate
                              select m.Date).Distinct();

                     var earlyMod = mod
                    .GroupBy(dt => dt.Date.Value)
                    .Select(z => z.OrderBy(y => y.Date).First())
                    .ToList();


                    return View(earlyMod);` err:  `DateTime? does not contain a definition of Date and no extension method 'Date' accepting a first argument of type 'DateTime?' could be found`

Comment: Can you please amend a bit so I can count the number of dates and store it in a variable too? Much Appreciated!

Comment: I would love to help with that but you should create a new question for that.

Comment: Please see this :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47449790/passing-the-list-of-dates-to-view-and-comparing-with-the-already-specified-dates

Answer (score 1):

You can use MoreLinq's `DistinctBy` for this. (You can install this via NuGet.)

Then you can do something like this:

```
using System;
using MoreLinq;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var dates = new []
            {
                new DateTime(2017, 11, 9, 8, 2, 9),
                new DateTime(2017, 11, 9, 5, 9, 23),
                new DateTime(2017, 11, 9, 15, 22, 51),
                new DateTime(2017, 11, 9, 17, 9, 23),
                new DateTime(2017, 11, 10, 11, 23, 04),
                new DateTime(2017, 11, 10, 16, 19, 57),
                new DateTime(2017, 11, 14, 10, 11, 11),
                new DateTime(2017, 11, 14, 18, 30, 30)
            };

            var distinctByDate = dates.OrderBy(date => date).DistinctBy(date => date.Date);

            foreach (var date in distinctByDate)
                Console.WriteLine(date);
        }
    }
}
```

Or if the dates are nullable, you would have to filter the null ones out:

```
        var dates = new DateTime?[]
        {
            new DateTime(2017, 11, 9, 17, 9, 23),
            new DateTime(2017, 11, 9, 15, 22, 51),
            new DateTime(2017, 11, 9, 8, 2, 9),
            null,
            new DateTime(2017, 11, 10, 11, 23, 04),
            new DateTime(2017, 11, 9, 17, 9, 23),
            null,
            new DateTime(2017, 11, 14, 10, 11, 11),
            new DateTime(2017, 11, 10, 16, 19, 57),
            new DateTime(2017, 11, 14, 18, 30, 30)
        };

        var distinctByDate = dates.Where(date => date.HasValue).OrderBy(date => date).DistinctBy(date => date?.Date);

        foreach (var date in distinctByDate)
            Console.WriteLine(date);
    }
```

Note that you can omit the `OrderBy()` if the dates are guaranteed to already be in order.

---

For completeness, here's the implementation of `DistinctBy` (I believe that this was first provided by Jon Skeet):

```
public static class EnumerableDistinctExt
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        return source.DistinctBy(keySelector, null);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, 
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        return distinctByImpl(source, keySelector, comparer);
    }

    static IEnumerable<TSource> distinctByImpl<TSource, TKey>(
        IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        var knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>(comparer);
        return source.Where(element => knownKeys.Add(keySelector(element)));
    }
}
```